# Should I tough it out (be patient until my training time finishes) or look for other job?

Tags: salary, new-job, job-change, discrimination

I work in a web developing company in an entry-level position.

I decided to take this position because I thought it was a good company to work for and I wanted to start my career. However the company is not doing well and I'm thinking about looking for a new position somewhere else.

I have been here for four months now, but I feel I'll need to wait at least 2 more months before I can apply for non-entry level (and therefore better paying) positions.

As I said, the company is not in great shape. The boss has complained so much that many of the experienced employees have left.As a result, the boss expects much more than I am capable of. I feel like I am performing well, but the boss doesn't appear to appreciate that, in fact he has put me down in front of others.

Last month he told me that I won't be paid until a new candidate is not hired. Until then, I should spend my time training on my own. However just three days later he then gave me a project to work on and it was two weeks until he hired an experienced candidate. I expected to be paid not the full salary but at least the remainder between when the candidate was hired and the end of the month. I haven't been paid, even though some of my colleagues have been. I feel like he is taking advantage of me.

I don't know whether to try looking job somewhere else (as I had to ask my parents for money to cover rent, bills etc which is making me lose my self respect) or just stick it out two more months, which will make it easier to find a better job.

I want your inputs as to whether i should wait for 2 more months by which i ll have 6 months experience even though he does not pay or should i start looking elsewhere from now itself.

Comment: Wait, you're working and he is refusing to pay your salary. What country are you in and have you looked into if this is even legal?

Comment: Actually he told me to take a break until he hires some1 but i said i would rather come to the office and learn things. But he gave me projects to work, so i think he has to pay me.

Comment: "He told me last month that he wont give my salary until a new candidate is not hired" - Even if you're willing to wait for your salary, you need to find out at least when this "not hiring someone" actually happens. One week, two weeks, months?

Comment: @Tom What country are you in?

Comment: Looking at his other SE profiles I believe he is based in India. I would suggest that the OP edits his public information if he's worried about his employer seeing this question.

Comment: Since people asked: I voted as unclear because: 1) the question in the title is off-topic (personal advice), 2) there is no actual question that I can see in the body of the post, just a lot of ranting, 3) the phrasing of this question is so obtuse that I can't actually tell what the OP's situation really is. This needs a drastic rewrite on the OP's part as there's no point in trying to answer by guessing at the particulars.

Comment: @Davor multiple moderators have now deleted some of your comments attacking other users - if you want a place to say anything you want without being "censored" you will find Stack Exchange is not the place for you. There are certain standards of conduct expected on this site, such as the [Be Nice](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) policy and [this meta post here](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/q/2979/2322).

Comment: I am from Srilanka.

Comment: my senior who was working earlier in the company has told me that there is vacancy in his company. I am considering attending interview there. based on your advice's.

Answer (score 12):

> He told me last month that he wont give my salary until a new
>   candidate is not hired

You are not being paid your basic salary, and you are still asking whether to stand up or not?  For heaven's sake, **you should.**

If at all you signed on the offer letter which includes the information about your salary details, then your boss is violating the agreement.

If you didn't, then I think you need to consider resignation.

Answer (score 9):

Start applying to new places a week ago. Not beeing paid for work you have done is unacceptable. Your company not doing that is not only illegal, but also a clear sign that they cannot be trusted.

Get out now. a 4 months versus 6 month employment on your CV has no negative effect big enough to stomach not beeing paid properly.

Comment: If OPs experience at 4 months is not enough to apply for "non-entry level" positions, I don't think 6 months will be any better.

Answer (score 6):

I was on the way to say "stay a few more months to have a better-looking resume" until I read that : *he wont give my salary until...* - then, there is no time for shaking. You owe them no loyalty in those conditions. Remake your resume now, and send it now. Or even yesterday.

Comment: very true but i did not wanted to take a impulsive decision which i would regret later so i posted for advices. thank you @gazzz0x2z.